# Glob seems broken inside makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am using some more advanced globs in my Makefile and they are failing badly.

In the shell I can run

```
ls {a,prefix-a}
```

and it works fine

But if I do that in a Makefile I get this

```
ls {a,prefix-a}
ls: cannot access '{a,prefix-a}': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:3: a] Error 2
```

Any idea of how to convince make to expand that glob rather than just passing it?

(I know I can use `sh -c 'blabla'`, I'm trying to do the clean thing).

Comment: IIRC, `{…}` is a bashism, and Make uses `sh` as a shell. But `{a,prefix-a}` simply expands to `a prefix-a`, so why not just use `ls a prefix-a`? But, again, why are you [using `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in a makefile?

Comment: Thanks :) Well am not using ls, it was just to make tests and achieve what I wanted to really do.

Comment: Also, I'm using a rather more complicated glob, that was the minimal easy one to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```